# understand "dependency injection framework is details" in clean architecture

Tags: dependency-injection, clean-architecture

When I was reading the book "clean architecture", it says "the goal of the architect is to create a shape for the system that recognizes policy as the most essential element of the system while making the details irrelevant to that policy. This allows decisions about those details to be delayed and deferred".

It then says database, dependency injection framework, web server etc are examples of those details.

The question is: I can develop the high-level policy without committing to details like database, as long as I create interface for database. But what I do not understand is that how to remove "dependency injection framework" from high-level policy code, since DI framework like Spring is responsible for  creating and auto-wiring objects.

Answer (score 2):

If your DI framework only use annotations or other mechanisms that requires altering of your higher policy to function, then that framework is not suitable to be used as DI tool in a clean architecture or any other application that should not be heavily dependent on an external library.

But Spring for example can be used without annotations.

First of all, usage of DI framework are not required in clean architecture. You can easily construct adapters, use case interactors etc. at the lowest "Framework and drivers"-layer and inject their dependencies by constructors or setters manually. No other layer will know how their dependencies were injected.

When using a DI framework, only the input adapters need to be externally resolved, other dependencies will be resolved and injected by the DI framework. This means that you can change between DI frameworks and even inject without any framework without affecting anything else but the outmost "Framework and drivers"-layer.